# Relation between some numbers and some percentage. What does represent $25$ in percent value?

Tags: percentages

I have a question about percentage. 
If

$0$ represents $10\%$

$15$ represents $100\%$

$30$ represents $200\%$

What does $25$ represent  in percent value?

I have obtained that $25$ represents $166\%$

**Updated:**

this is a hypothetical situation. for example if you are a student and you have to pass an exam. If you go to exam and you do not anything ($0$ tasks) you will achieve $10\%$. If you go to exam and solve $15$ tasks you will achieve $100\%$ and if you solve $30$ tasks you will achieve $200\%$. I think we can supose that $0\%$ is realized when you do not participate to exam (you are absent)

Comment: Could you elaborate what means "$0$ represents $10$%"?

Comment: If 30 represents 200%, then 0 represents 0%... So your question is not really clear.

Answer (score 2):

Interpolating *linearly* between the points $(15,100)$ and $(30,200)$ indeed gives $(25,166\frac{2}{3})$.

However, there is an infinite number of functions going through the points $(0,10)$, $(15,100)$ and $(30,200)$, so you might want to clarify what *represents* means in your question  :)

Comment: It also gives $(0,0)$ which contradicts initial question.

Comment: this is a hypothetical situation. for example if you are a student and you have to pass an exam. If you go to exam and you do not anything (0 tasks) you will achieve 10%. If you go to exam and solve 15 tasks you will achieve 100% and if you solve 30 tasks you will achieve 200%. I think we can supose that 0% is realized when you do not participate to exam (you are absent).

Comment: @Abstraction, of course it does, though that is extrapolation. Whatever interpolation method you use, based on the points $(0,10), (15,100)$ and $(30,200)$, you'll never arrive at $(0,0)$. Based on the points $(15,100)$ and $(30,200)$ you might - as you pointed out - though I do not see why that is relevant.

Comment: @luli. Advancing from solving $0$ tasks to $15$ tasks (i.e. $15$ extra tasks) earns you $90\%$ extra. Advancing from solving $15$ tasks to $30$ tasks (i.e. $15$ extra tasks) earns you $100\%$ extra. Because of this discrepancy, there is no unambiguous answer as to what percentage-value should be assigned to $25$ tasks solved. There could be a really complex function describing this.